# How to alter data when computed property changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reactive-programming

In my vue.js template I have a navigation 'pop-up/modal' component that is toggled on the users click. The default position of this navigation bar is closed, however, when a certain computed property (in this case, once some questions are answered) evaluates to true I want the default position of the bar to be 'popped-up' *without* losing the toggle-ability of the modal component.

I have tried directly changing the data in the computed property but have since learned (from looking around on SO) that this is bad practice. After some research it appeared that setting up a watcher which calls a method when the computed property `allAnswered` returns `true` was the way to go but I cannot get this to work at all.

It's part of a much larger template so I'm attaching the relevant parts of the code below:

```
<template>
    <div class="m-btn__nav" @click="showNav = true"><h4>Where to?</h4></div>
    <Navigation v-if="showNav" @close="showNav = false"></Navigation>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            showNav: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        allAnswered () {
            let q = this.getRoomQuestions(1)
            let a = []
            for (let index = 0; index < q.length; ++index) {
                a.push(q[index].answered)
            }
            if (Object.keys(a).every(i => a[i])) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        allAnswered: function (n) {
            this.updateNav()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateNav: function () {
          this.showNav = true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I expected the watcher `allAnswered` to fire when the computed property `allAnswered` changed from returning `false` to `true` and fire the method `updateNav` to change the `showNav` data. The result is that even when the `allAnswered` computed property re-evaluates, it does not fire the watcher/method and change the data.

Comment: What's the story behind using `Object.keys` on an array?

Comment: `a` is an array of json objects

Comment: But `keys` is just pulling the indexes of the array. It isn't applied to the individual elements. You could write that line as `a.every(v => v)`

Comment: I feel like `allAnswered` can be simplified to `return this.getRoomQuestions(1).every(q => q.answered)`

Comment: It's not clear that `allAnswered` _should_ be re-evaluating. It does not use any reactive variables. It only calls a function to get data. What is the source of the data? Is it reactive?

Answer (score 0):

Computeds are ONLY evaluated upon usage. 
You are not utilizing your computed allAnswered(), therefore the output is not changing.
Try placing it in template or a mounted() hook.

Comment: Could I then still watch it?

Comment: Yes, you can still watch the 'value' of the computed, but consider it null until it is referenced somewhere in your component (other than a watcher).